# Android Kotlin getting a JSON variable with special character

Tags: android, json, variables, kotlin

I have a JSON Variable called

**on_sale? : false**

but cannot call it in Kotlin, because of the "?" in the name. I get back a "null" value even if the variable is **"true"**

is it even possible to call a variable in Kotlin with a special character in it?

Thank you!

Comment: Post your code buddy! You can't have a `?` in a Kotlin variable name, but there are probably a lot of workarounds for handling JSON with weird names, and people will be able to help you if they can see what you're trying to do

Comment: Do You use GSON? Or what library to convert JSON to Kotlin class?

Comment: yes sorry for not clarifying that i am using GSON and Okhttp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use GSON and `serilizedname`. more info [here](https://howtodoinjava.com/gson/gson-serializedname/).
this will change your variable name to ***on_sale?*** in your json

```
class SomeClass {

    @SerializedName(value = "on_sale?")
    val onSale: Boolean? = false
}
```

provide more code for more help

Comment: Thank you so much! This worked! Sorry for not providing more code. But definitely respect your ability to answer it with very little information. Once again Thank you!

Comment: glad I could help :)